# Dotmailer connector API endpoint cannot be empty

Tags: magento2.2, frontend-error

An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.

```
[2018-01-12 02:00:11] main.CRITICAL: Dotmailer connector API endpoint cannot be empty. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): Dotmailer connector API endpoint cannot be empty. at /home/site/public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Model/Apiconnector/Client.php:118)"} []
```

Hello, I just used commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
./n98-magerun2.phar cache:clean
```

That's it, I'm using the latest Magento version at the momment: 2.2.2.

Answer (score 6):

I've created a github issue to look at this:

https://github.com/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/issues/495

We've identified a cron job that is attempting to initialise the api without checking if its enabled first. We're looking for other places that similar behaviour may be happening.

Comment: In short, best thing to do for now is to disable tha Dotmailer module if you don't plan to use it. `bin/magento module:disable Dotdigitalgroup_Email`